# Error adding layers in neural network in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist             
from tensorflow.keras import models                     
from tensorflow.keras import layers                     
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical         

network=models.Sequential()    # this initializes a sequential model that we will call network
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu')    # this adds a dense hidden layer 
network.add(layers.Dense(8, activation = 'softmax'))  # this is the output layer
```

I am trying to create a 2 layer neural network model in tensorflow and am getting this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-0dde2ff676f8>", line 7
network.add(layers.Dense(8, activation = 'softmax'))  # this is the output layer
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

May I know why I'm getting this error for output layer but not for hidden layer? Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a `)` on line 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `missed a closing bracket`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist             
from tensorflow.keras import models                     
from tensorflow.keras import layers                     
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical         

network=models.Sequential()    # this initializes a sequential model that we will call network
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))    # this adds a dense hidden layer 
network.add(layers.Dense(8, activation = 'softmax'))  # this is the output layer
```